# PHP- How to run cron jobs one after another like job queue

Tags: php, linux, cron

How to run cron jobs one after another, like job queue ?

I am working on project which has near about 20+ cron jobs, most of them starts every hour and are very DB intensive, so i would like to have something like job queue which will start one cron job after another ,so not all 20+ job start at the start of new hour and make my server unavailable.

Is there per-built system for something like this ?
or any other easy way to add job queue functionality to the linux cron. ?

Answer (score 6):

Write a bash script to run the commands in sequence, and add that to the crontab.

Eg create a file called something like phpjobs.sh with the commands to run the jobs in order:-

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/php -q <yourfile1.php>
/usr/bin/someothercommand
/usr/bin/php -q <yourfile2.php>
/usr/bin/php -q <yourfile3.php>
```

then make it executable

```
chmod 755 phpjobs.sh
```

Then add it to the crontab to run every hour

```
0 * * * *  root   /path/to/phpjobs.sh
```